# You need 3 elements for $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I keep hearing that if you have an $\mathbb R^3$ space you need 3 elements to fill the space.

1. So, let's consider a column vector. I understood 3 elements to mean = 3 column vectors with 3 elements each. As you can't span $\mathbb R^3$ with JUST one or two vectors even if they each have 3 elements. Correct?
2. Could you technically somehow take 2 column vectors with 4 elements to span $\mathbb R^3$? I'm guessing not.

Comment: column vectors with $4$ elements are not in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: note that you need a collection of at least three linearly independent vectors to span $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @ed8484 no. By definition $\mathbb{R}^3 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ which is a ordered triple all coming from $\mathbb{R}$. They can't have four elements.

Comment: I think you are looking for the concept of dimension, and asking yourself questions like this will help you to clarify your thinking. In general $n$ vectors span a space of dimension at most $n$ (they may be linearly dependent). If you think about three dimensional space you can find a lot of two dimensional spaces within it (any plane) - if you fix an origin any plane through the origin is a two dimensional subspace and any line through the origin is a one dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 3):

To the first question. You need three vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3\in \mathbb{R}^3$. It's correct. The elements refers to vectors $v\in \mathbb{R}^3$. But that is not enough to span $\mathbb{R}^3$, they have to be linearly independent; i.e.
$$a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3=0\text{ iff }a_1=a_2=a_3=0.$$

The second question. No. First because a vector with 4 entries lives in $\mathbb{R}^4$. But if you consider $\mathbb{R}^3$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Again you need 3 vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3\in \mathbb{R}^4$ that are linearly independent to span $\mathbb{R}^3$, but here the question is a little bit different. Think of $\mathbb{R}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$. You can embed it as any line that passes through the origin, so you have many representations of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, same thing happens with $\mathbb{R}^3$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: A line through the origin would be a subspace of R^2? (ie. it be a subset..as we would need a plane to fill R^2?)

Comment: I might also be confusing the terms elements and entries? or are these interchangeable?

Comment: Here is some unambiguous terminology: $v\in R^n$ is an *element* of the *set* $R^n$ or specific to linear algebra, a *vector* in $n$ dimensional real space and the $v_i$ in $v=(v_1,\dotsc, v_n)$ are *coordinates* or *entries* of $v$ and are elements of $R$

Comment: @ed8484 A line through the origin is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with dimension 1, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ as vector spaces. That is what I mean saying embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Nap D. Lover -> Here is my understanding, you tell me where it is wrong. So is entries simply referring to specific values/entries in the vector, and the elements is referring to the field that is over the vector space? (in this case R)